# Docker Swarm Fault-tolerant Scheduling

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In this blog the docker developer said that in the future they will implement the Fault-tolerant Scheduling
https://blog.docker.com/2015/02/scaling-docker-with-swarm/

Does somebody know what is the advance about this?